# Employment in academia for doctorates w/o same field undergrad

Tags: phd, career-path, physics, engineering, independent-researcher

I'm an undergraduate in Mechanical Engineering interested in a career in academia, especially Physics. A middle aged person in India (from where I am) I recently met told me he couldn't find employment in academia in India or abroad after completing his doctorate in a Physics field, because he did an undergrad in Mechanical Engineering. Is this situation where there is difficulty finding employment when doctorate and previous education do not match generally true in academia, Physics or otherwise, or probably a very specific problem?

Comment: My undergrad was Electrical Engineering, my PhD was in Materials Science, and I'm now building a new pulsed power accelerator. Sounds like a specific problem to me.

Comment: People switch fields relatively frequently between the undergraduate studies and the PhD. I rather suspect that he is attributing the failure of finding an employment in academia to this when the issue is actually elsewhere.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The person told me the catch was that he was expected to teach subjects he wasn't good at, is that situation common ?

Comment: Is it that they can't find a job in physics because the physics department sees the undergrad degree and scoffs, or is it that they are short on mech eng instructors and hope someone with a mech eng background and PhD in physics might be able to fill the holes? The latter seems far more plausible to me, or the other alternative that they are completely wrong about why they can't find a job.

Comment: @BryanKrause Apparently the former. He says universities denied employment on the basis that he potentially could be incapable of lecturing physics students because he held a Mechanical Engineering degree.

Comment: I think it's more likely he's just making up a story and getting it wrong, or someone gave that reason but was lying. Unless his actual physics PhD didn't really involve physics and doesn't demonstrate competency in that field.

Comment: @BryanKrause Oh that makes sense. Thanks for the input !

Comment: It's certainly true that a faculty member in most disciplines in the US will be expected to be able to teach a variety of courses in that discipline and that not having sufficient background in the discipline (because for example the candidate has made a late switch into the discipline) can be a negative on the job market.

Comment: @BrianBorchers From your assessment I'm picking up that having sound knowledge (which is any case needed for a PhD) in some subjects to teach related to ONE particular field, say solid state physics, should be safe. One won't be expected to handle subjects beyond that field?

Comment: @Gaurav You'd probably want to be able to convince the department that can teach introductory physics classes too. There's usually a lot more of them than there are courses in, say solid-state physics, thus requiring more instructors. Someone with a ME background likely knows the mechanics parts well, but might not have taken much electromagnetism or optics (or so-called modern physics, if that's included).

Comment: @Gaurav  in a large department, you might be able to limit your teaching to say "solid state physics", but in a smaller department (and there are lots of small physics and math departments in the US) you might have to teach a much wider variety of physics courses.  I work in a relatively small mathematics department and have taught undergraduate courses in calculus, linear algebra, differential equations, combinatorics, probability, statistics, numerical analysis, mathematical modeling, and operations research.  That kind of breadth is valued in smaller departments.

Comment: @Anyon Got it, thanks. But that doesn't mean I'll be filtered out pre-interview for being _assumed_ to be not suited, right?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Understood, thanks for the help and time!

Comment: @Gaurav I would expect that, if they're otherwise interested in your profile but not sure if you can teach the required courses, they'll ask you about it at some point (as in stochastic's answer).

Comment: @Anyon Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally not a problem, and many departments may even consider having a more diverse background an advantage.

I have an engineering undergraduate degree and graduate degrees in physics and math, and I was asked (only once) in one of my interviews if I am comfortable teaching undergraduate physics courses given that my undergraduate degree is in another field. If you can confidently say yes to this question and can back it up, there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 5):

Don't base life decisions on anecdotes. I'm sure such cases exist, and, other cases in almost any combination. But your future as an academic, or even in industry, will depend far more on your later work and far more than that on the potential for success that you can demonstrate to anyone in a position to hire you.

But it would be a mistake to stay in Mechanical Engineering for life just for such a reason. It might be a reason to switch earlier, rather than later, but only so that your path into a physics doctoral program might be eased a bit.

But, a single case is always a poor indicator as there are always, potentially, other, unstated, reasons for the outcome.

Create your own life. But work hard at it.

Comment: Thanks, really helped ! The person I'm referring to told me lecturing unrelated subjects was his problem. Is lecturing part necessarily part of the job profile ?

Comment: That may vary by country and certainly by field and by institution. Most academics, worldwide, do some teaching. It may be a lot or a little. But to get an academic position you need, also, to be seen as a "good fit" for the current and projected needs of the institution.

Comment: Basically, though research might be very specific that eliminates potential lecturing in some subjects, unis might still consider if the candidate's research is aligned with the institute's stated research areas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have a permanent lectureship in a field that I don't even have a PhD in, let alone an earlier degree...and I lecture in the field too, despite never having even taken a class in it. It makes sense if you follow my research progression, but that's the point, everyone is different. Note this is social sciences/humanities, but nothing is clear cut in academia, and a different undergraduate degree is particularly meaningless post PhD.

Comment: All my degrees are in theoretical math. About 90% of my teaching has been computer science (and not as just "misspelled math").